# Dynamically replace the “src” attributes of all <img> tags (redux)

Tags: php, parsing, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically replace the “src” attributes of all <img> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808285/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags)

Funny story: I posted [this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808285/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags) a short time ago, but instead of getting something I could, you know, use, all I got was a lot of dogma about the evils of using regex to parse HTML. So here goes again.

I have some HTML and want to replace the "src" attributes of all the img tags so that they point to copies of the identical images (although with different file names) on another host.

For instance, given these three tags

```
<IMG SRC="../graphics/pumpkin.gif" ALT="pumpkin">
<IMG BORDER="5" SRC="redball.gif" ALT="*"> 
<img alt="cool image" src="http://www.crunch.com/pic.jpg"/>
```

I would like them replaced with

```
<IMG SRC="http://myhost.com/cache/img001.gif" ALT="pumpkin">
<IMG BORDER="5" SRC="http://myhost.com/cache/img002.gif" ALT="*"> 
<img alt="cool image" src="http://myhost.com/cache/img003.jpg"/>
```

I am trying to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but I'm not getting it.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>
<IMG SRC="../graphics/pumpkin.gif" ALT="pumpkin">
<IMG BORDER="5" SRC="redball.gif" ALT="*"> 
<img alt="cool image" src="http://www.crunch.com/pic.jpg"/>
</body></html>');
```

What do I do next?

Comment: Have you tried using DOMDocument()?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of  [Dynamically replace the "src" attributes of all <img> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808285/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags), as this isn't the way to do it, but you're right the answers could have been more to the point (although, checking out the DOM documentation isn't that hard, and I find it easier (subjective) and way faster (objective) then that 'Simple HTML DOM Parser')

Answer (score 6):

If you care to go the way of DOMDocument():

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($imgs as $img){
    $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
    if ($alt == 'pumpkin'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img001.gif';    
    } else if ($alt== '*'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img002.gif';
    } else if ($alt== 'cool image'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img003.jpg';
    }
    $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $src );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted has the answer:

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```

Of course, you will need to modify the tag/attribute/value names to meet your specific needs.