# how to display Object of class DOMElement in php

Tags: php

need your help..
I've seen a great answer from [Dynamically replace the “src” attributes of all  tags (redux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808746/dynamically-replace-the-src-attributes-of-all-img-tags-redux), but I don't know how to display from the code below

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($imgs as $img){
    $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
    if ($alt == 'pumpkin'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img001.gif'; 
    } else if ($alt== '*'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img002.gif';
    } else if ($alt== 'cool image'){
        $src = 'http://myhost.com/cache/img003.jpg';
    }
    $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $src );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) method, after you modify the image, by changing this line:

```
$img->setAttribute( 'src' , $src );
```

To this:

```
$img->setAttribute( 'src' , $src );
echo $dom->saveHTML( $img);
```